# how to execute for loop for items checked in 3 checkedlistbox

Tags: vb.net

i made a report for taking output of employees in a company.i made a code for that.but it only show the first items checked.how to impliment for loop in this.

```
   Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    For i = 0 To Employee_Bank_dtl.CheckedListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Step i + 1
        If Employee_Bank_dtl.CheckedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i) = CheckState.Checked Then
            Dim xx As String = (CType(Employee_Bank_dtl.CheckedListBox1.Items(i), DataRowView))("VC_BRNAME")
            For j = 0 To Employee_Bank_dtl.CheckedListBox2.Items.Count - 1 Step j + 1
                If Employee_Bank_dtl.CheckedListBox2.GetItemCheckState(j) = CheckState.Checked Then
                    Dim yy As String = (CType(Employee_Bank_dtl.CheckedListBox2.Items(j), DataRowView))("vc_empstatus")
                    For k = 0 To Employee_Bank_dtl.CheckedListBox3.Items.Count - 1 Step k + 1
                        If Employee_Bank_dtl.CheckedListBox3.GetItemCheckState(k) = CheckState.Checked Then
                            Dim zz As String = (CType(Employee_Bank_dtl.CheckedListBox3.Items(k), DataRowView))("vc_value")
                            Dim str = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
                            conobj.readdata(str)
                            conobj._adpt.Fill(Me.DataSet10.BRANCH_MAST)
                            Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next i
```

Comment: Instead of looping and looking at checkedstate, just use the CheckedItems property of the CheckboxLists. If that doesn't resolve your problem then explain more. You go to a lot of trouble to set variables (xx, yy, zz) but you never use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its my mistake replacing k + 1 to +1 in the 3rd loop will got the right answer

Answer (score 0):

You should increment through the collection of items like this not the way you are doing it.  You should be able to find the properties you are looking for.  Set a break point within the inner loop and right click on quickwatch on the item and you will see all the properties of that item which will contain what your looking for.

```
    For Each item In CheckedListBox1.Items
        'set the item property to the right property that holds "VC_BRNAME"
        If item.property = "VC_BRNAME" Then

        End If
        If item.checkstate.checked = True Then

        End If

    Next
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..i don't get the idea please explain or give a code for this